# ¿Cual de estas dos formas es la mejor forma de acceder a los archivos .css y .js?

Tags: enlace, script, href, src

Actualmente tengo una aplicacion donde accedo a diferentes archivos .js y .css y lo hago de la siguiente forma:

```
<link href='vista/assets/style/index.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

Esa forma es la mas estandar que conozco y lo que hace es comunicarse a la carpetas hijas a partir de una base.

Pero tambien eh visto la siguiente forma:

```
$host="http://localhost:8080/softicket/SoftTicket/trunk/";

    <link href=<?php echo $host.'/vista/assets/style/index.css' ?> rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

Las dos formas funcionan correctamente, pero la forma numero dos obtiene toda la ruta completa y la primera solo accede a carpetas hijas. No se si haya mucha diferencia o da exactamente lo mismo la forma en que se accede a dichos elementos web.

La verdad es que mi situacion es que quiero que al momento de subir a un servidor o tener que cambiar de servidor y digamos la ruta se modificara constantemente en un futuro, solo es una posibilidad, entonces queira ver la forma mas rapida de hacer que ese cambio fuera facil de hacer y de asimilar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Realmente la mejor manera de hacerlo en con la primera opción, usar PHP dentro del código HTML no es muy buena idea en la actualidad, queremos menos código espagueti.

**Observación:** La forma correcta de importar tus estilos es:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="tu_ruta/tu_archivo.css"/>
```

El atributo type se puede omitir desde HTML5, pero para versiones anteriores de HTML deberías usarlo.

Los archivos .js deberías importarlos con la siguiente sintaxis:

```
<script src="tu_ruta/tu_archivo.js"></script>
```